# perl dbi prepare with variable table column name

Tags: perl, dbi

I have used the following code many times before when inserting values into database tables using perl

```
my $SRV='xxx';
my $DB='dbname';        
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$SRV/$DB", "user", "pword" )  or die "impossible de se connecter à $SRV / $DB";

my $insert_T1 = "INSERT INTO tablename (ColA, ColB) VALUES ( ?, ?) " ;
my $insert_T1_sth = $db->prepare($insert_T1) ;
```

Later in the code I can then call the following to do the insertion

```
$insert_T1_sth->execute('val1','val2');
$insert_T1_sth->execute('val3','val4');
```

So basically when I use the prepare function above I can replace the entries I want to insert by question marks and then put the values of these question marks in the execute statements later on.

So to my question: Can I use question marks in place of column names in the prepare statement? I'm thinking no because when I try the following I get a runtime error on the line where the execute statement(s) are.

```
my $SRV='xxx';
my $DB='dbname';        
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$SRV/$DB", "user", "pword" )  or die "impossible de se connecter à $SRV / $DB";
$db->{AutoCommit} = 0 ;

my $insert_T1 = "INSERT INTO tablename (ColA, ?) VALUES ( ?, ?) " ;
my $insert_T1_sth = $db->prepare($insert_T1) ;
```

Then later, as before, use

```
$insert_T1_sth->execute('colname1','val1','val2');
$insert_T1_sth->execute('colname2','val3','val4');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use dynamic column names with `prepare` like you are trying to do.

Your column names shouldn't be known to the user, and therefore don't really need to be part of the parameters, since they are not sensitive (and don't need to be protected against SQL injection). Preparing is still useful for performances though.

What I'd suggest is to do a prepare for each of you column name, and store those in a hash:

```
my @col_names = qw(colname1 colname2);
my %inserts;
for my $col (@col_names) {
    $inserts{$col} = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (ColA, $col) VALUES (?, ?)");
}
...
$inserts{colname1}->execute('val1', 'val2');
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Dada, unfortunately I have about 900 column names

Comment: @Chazg76 So what? There is nothing inherently wrong to preparing 900 different insert statements. Well, your database sounds oddly designed, and my first reaction when I see that you need 900 different inserts on different column names is that you need to rethink your database, but who knows, there might there is a good justification..